# How to add variable into module context - Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I ran into a problem, where I need to bind some variable to context of module. I have two folders : Controllers and Models. In models, I have a model like this :

```
exports = {
  name: String,
  password: String
}
```

and the Controller looks like this :

```
exports = {
  onMessage: (message) {
    Model.doSomething();
  }
}
```

So I need to access the Model in the Controller while not require-ing it. I don't think loading the Model and giving it to global is good practice for this. I am looking for something like `MyNodeJsModule.addVarToContext(Model);`

The thing why I don't want to require model in controller is, I need the model to be loaded by external system and let the external system replace the Model by database-accessable model.

Comment: Why wouldn't require() it?

Comment: Please read to the end. I need the model to be changed by external system that will require it. After that, I need to get the changed Model into the context.

Answer (score 0):

probably you have to change Controller like this?

```
module.exports = function(Model) {
  return {
      onMessage: function(message) {
         Model.doSomething();
      }
  };
}
```

Comment: There's not jut one model to inject. Also I may want to inject more to one context.

Comment: Of 'coz you can set some variable to global scope. But this is not a good idea. As a result you have a choice : require vs argument (you can set argument as a array or object and you have a possibility to pass not only Model to context)

Comment: I know thats not a good idea, that's why I am looking for solution to bind the variables to the context.

Answer (score 0):

Not quite sure what you need exactly but you can export `Controller` as a constructor and then bind each instance to a specific model.

So, in controller:

```
// Constructor
var Controller = function(model){
  this._model = model;
}

Controller.prototype.onMessage = function(message) {
  this._model.doSomething(message);
};

Controller.prototype.setModel = function(newModel){
  this._model = newModel;
}

exports.Controller = Controller;
```

Then (externally):

```
var ModelController = require('./controller').Controller;

var modelController1 = new ModelController(model1);
var modelController2 = new ModelController(model2);

modelController1.setModel(model2);
modelController2.setModel(model1);
```

Comment: The thing I want is, to Inject the models into Controllers so then I can just call them like global variables, but they are global just for one module. That's why I wanted the context bind.